# Can I create a numerical variable from the combination of other numerical variables?

Tags: regression, numerics, variable

I am working with a dataset that contains limnological parameters. This dataset contains turbidity-related measures in different units and consequently different ranges. Is there a way to create a numerical variable called "Turbidity" that comprises all the measurements in different unities? I want to use this variable in a linear regression to assess its relationship with plankton parameters (abundance, also numeric).

I can not just use the measures together as they are now in different units because it will create a range that goes from 0.1 to 1000 in absolute numbers and some turbidity units are high at 10 while others are low at 50. I also don´t want to use them separately because some have only a few measurements, so I´m trying to make my dataset more robust by joining numerical variables into one.